# JPA nested inner join query

Tags: java, sql, jpa

I have 3 tables and a ManyToMany relationship between usuario and projeto, and I'm having a headche to make it search accordly :

```
usuario
+-------------+-------------+
| idMatricula | nomeUsuario | 
+-------------+-------------+
| 1           | Victor      | 
| 12345       | Juquinha    |
| 2           | Nilton      | 
| 3           | Fatima      | 
| 4           | Bianca      | 
| 4422        | Pedrinho    | 
+-------------+-------------+

projeto
+-----------+----------------+--------------+
| idprojeto | nomeProjeto    | faseProjeto  |
+-----------+----------------+--------------+
|         1 | APS_6_semestre | Em Andamento |
|         2 | APS_7_semestre | Em testes    |
|         3 | APS_8_semestre | Em testes    |
|         4 | TCC            | Concluido    |
+-----------+----------------+--------------+

projeto_has_usuario
+-------------------+---------------------+
| projeto_idprojeto | usuario_idMatricula |
+-------------------+---------------------+
|                 1 | 1                   |
|                 1 | 2                   |
|                 1 | 3                   |
|                 2 | 2                   |
+-------------------+---------------------+
```

I'm trying to query only the projects associated to the user, but my query doesnt work and I dont know if it is a semantic error or an annotation error. Here is my mapped class:

Projeto:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="projeto")
public class Projeto {

@GeneratedValue
@Id
@Column(name="idprojeto", nullable = false)
private int idprojeto;

@Column(name="nomeProjeto", nullable = false)
private String nomeProjeto;

@Column(name="faseProjeto", nullable = false)
private String faseProjeto;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy="projetos")
private List<Usuario> usuarios;
```

Usuario:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="usuario")
public class Usuario {

@Id
@Column(name="idMatricula", nullable = false)
private String id;

@Column(name="nomeUsuario", nullable = false)
private String nomeUsuario;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name="projeto_has_usuario",
joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="usuario_idMatricula")},
inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="projeto_idprojeto")})
private List<Projeto> projetos;
```

Here is my query:

```
TypedQuery<Usuario> listaUsuario = manager.createQuery("SELECT u FROM Usuario as u", Usuario.class);
// Some validation ..
    TypedQuery<Projeto> listaTabela = manager.createQuery("SELECT p FROM projeto p "
    + "JOIN p.usuarios u WHERE p.idprojeto MEMBER OF u.projetos", Projeto.class);

    for (Projeto projetos : listaTabela.getResultList()) {
        System.out.println("Nome: " + projetos.getNomeProjeto() + "\nID: " + projetos.getIdprojeto()
        + "\nFase: " + projetos.getFaseProjeto());
```

Returns me:

```
Nome: APS_6_semestre
ID: 1
Fase: Em Andamento
```

I'm using Eclipse IDE 4.7.2, Hibernate 5.2.12 and JPA 2.1.

Comment: This query doesn't make much sense: an int can't be a member of a collection containing projects. What is the query **supposed** to do?

Comment: Its supposed to return the "Nome", "ID", and "Fase" of the projects belonging to the "Usuario" from the first query.

Comment: Then your second query needs to pass a user as **parameter** to the second one. It should look like `select p from Usuario u join u.projetos p where u = :theUser`. But this query is useless, since you can just use `user.getProjetos()` to get the projects of a user.

Comment: Great, gonna test in the next hours. Thanks

Comment: @JBNizet Using user.getProjetos() returns `Projeto@4d7f9a85"`, how to print each element as string? Tried `.forEach()` without sucess. EDIT: Did it using `for (Projeto p : user.getProjetos())`. Thanks :)